# I am getting a runtime error for my mediaplayer class when I try to play audio(Android/Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, media-player, emulation

I am trying to make a notification app and when I click the button it should make a beep sound while the notification pops up.

When I click the button the notification comes up but I am  getting error in the runtime with sound.I think "emulator is not responding" error at run time.

I am getting android mediaplayer error:

> 07-19 19:32:28.846: I/StagefrightPlayer(110):
>   setDataSource('android.resourse://com.example.status/2130968576')
>   07-19 19:32:28.846: E/MediaPlayer(198): error (1, -2147483648) 07-19
>   19:32:28.846: W/NotificationService(198): error loading sound for
>   android.resourse://com.example.status/2130968576 07-19 19:32:28.846:
>   W/NotificationService(198): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.:
>   status=0x1 07-19 19:32:28.846: W/NotificationService(198):    at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method) 07-19 19:32:28.846:
>   W/NotificationService(198):   at
>   com.android.server.NotificationPlayer$CreationAndCompletionThread.run(NotificationPlayer.java:90)
>   07-19 19:32:28.976: D/dalvikvm(273): GC_CONCURRENT freed 701K, 55%
>   free 3028K/6599K, external 2434K/2980K, paused 8ms+4ms

Here is the Java code just in case:

```
package com.example.status;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        Notification notify = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more, 
                                "This is important", System.currentTimeMillis());
                        Context context = MainActivity.this;
                        CharSequence title = "You have been notified";
                        CharSequence details = "Continue with what you are doing";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
                        notify.setLatestEventInfo(context,title,details,pending);
                        notify.sound = Uri.parse("android.resourse://com.example.status/" + R.raw.beep);

                        nm.notify(0, notify);





            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the following:

```
android.resourse://com.example.status/2130968576
```

Try spelling "resource" with a 'c':

```
android.resource://com.example.status/2130968576
```

Answer (score 0):

spelling `resourse` with a **s** is why you are getting that error.